# Change ckeditor table dialogue defaults

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

Quite simply the ckeditor table dialogue defaults to a table width of 500, yes the client should be told to delete that value, but I would like to alter the default table width value programmatically to 100%.

I have found other posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12477003/352040) but in Drupal 8 land where do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways with a script we can call, for example, ckeditor_settings_modifier.js containing:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if(dialogName == 'table') {
    var info = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
    info.get('txtWidth')['default'] = '100%';
  }
});
```

This script should be added in one of these places through libraries:

- only in the theme of your website (if you use it also for editing)
- in your administration theme in order it works in normal node edit mode, and in your website theme in order it works in quick edit mode
- in a custom module in which you can use for example some conditional rules that control the loading of the script.

In any choosen settings it is important to declare the dependency on the core/ckeditor.

This is the case of a module (my_module containing a js folder with ckeditor_settings_modifier.js), in my_module.libraries.yml:

```
ckeditor_settings_modifier:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/ckeditor_settings_modifier.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/ckeditor
```

in my_module.module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 */
function my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // add ckeditor_modifier in case the user has the role of administrator
  $roles = Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  if(in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_module/ckeditor_settings_modifier';
  }
}
```

It works on Drupal 8.4.4 and CKEditor 4.8

Answer (score -2):

You really need to modify this `width=""` property value?
In HTML5 this property is deprecated, anyway you can use it, and override it behavior via CSS (any value declared for the table through CSS will override the property value without need of use `!important` or something like that).

Comment: This is about the ckeditor table dialogue which has a default width of 500, yes I know I can style it to override it in display, but that does not solve overriding the value in the dialogue.